# RE question : transfer exe transfer file from Ubuntu oracle virtual box to host machine (windows 7 )

Tags: virtualbox, transfer

i want to transfer executable file from Ubuntu to windows , i try via shared folder its ok but when i open executable file in windows the file is not defined ( not exe file )

- More information :
  the exe file (sphinx3_align ) is part of package sphinx3 tool , after run sphinx3 tool in ubuntu  copy sphinx3_align from usr/local/bin to shared folder ( i need it to put in another virtual box )  , but when i open in windows the file not defind
- Detaile : safia@safia-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$ file sphinx3_align sphinx3_align: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=d4584be6f1adc0b0a8471cd8e774a79c53b1f7f3, not stripped

  Anyone have any idea about this problem , help me ,Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can't run Linux programs in Windows (unless you use some kind of emulator) nor Windows programs in Linux (again except if you are using Wine or similar software).

Comment: yes , but i don't run program in window , just i need copy of these program to put in another Linux machine , clear ??

Comment: No. What do you mean with "when i open executable file in windows the file is not defined ( not exe file )"?

Comment: But if you are copying a file using Linux as a bridge it will lost it's unix permissions. Maybe the new file just lacks execution permission?.